# Помогите решить (99,14): error CS1061 ошибка находится в void flip()

Tags: c#, unity3d

`(99,14): error CS1061'Transform' does not contain a definition for 'eulerAngels' and no accessible extension method 'eulerAngels' accepting a first argument of type 'Transform' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerContorller : MonoBehaviour
{
    public enum ProjectAxis { onlyX = 0, xAndY = 1 };
public ProjectAxis projectAxis = ProjectAxis.onlyX;
public float speed = 150;
public float drag = 100;
public float addForce = 7;
public bool lookAtCursor;
public KeyCode leftButton = KeyCode.A;
public KeyCode rightButton = KeyCode.D;
public KeyCode upButton = KeyCode.W;
public KeyCode downButton = KeyCode.S;
public KeyCode addForceButton = KeyCode.Space;
public bool isFacingRight = true;
private Vector3 direction;
private float moveInput;
private float vertical;
private float horizontal;
private Rigidbody2D body;
private float rotationY;
private bool jump;

void Start()
{
    body = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    body.fixedAngle = true;

    if (projectAxis == ProjectAxis.xAndY)
    {
        body.gravityScale = 0;
        body.drag = drag;
    }
}

void OnCollisionStay2D(Collision2D coll)
{
    if (coll.transform.tag == "Ground")
    {
        body.drag = drag;
        jump = true;
    }
}

void OnCollisionExit2D(Collision2D coll)
{
    if (coll.transform.tag == "Ground")
    {
        body.drag = 0;
        jump = false;
    }
}

void FixedUpdate()
{
    body.AddForce(direction * body.mass * speed);

    if (Mathf.Abs(body.velocity.x) > speed / 100f)
    {
        body.velocity = new Vector2(Mathf.Sign(body.velocity.x) * speed / 100f, body.velocity.y);
    }

    if (projectAxis == ProjectAxis.xAndY)
    {
        if (Mathf.Abs(body.velocity.y) > speed / 100f)
        {
            body.velocity = new Vector2(body.velocity.x, Mathf.Sign(body.velocity.y) * speed / 100f);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (Input.GetKey(addForceButton) && jump)
        {
            body.velocity = new Vector2(0, addForce);
        }
    }
}

void Flip()
{
    if (projectAxis == ProjectAxis.xAndY)
    {
        isFacingRight = !isFacingRight;
        Vector3 theScale = transform.localScale;
        theScale.x *= -1;
        transform.localScale = theScale;

        if (moveInput < 0)
        {
            transform.eulerAngels = new Vector3(0, 180, 0);


        }
        else if (moveInput > 0)
        {
            transform.eulerAngels = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);

        }
    }
}

void Update()
{
    if (lookAtCursor)
    {
        Vector3 lookPos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y, Camera.main.transform.position.z));
        lookPos = lookPos - transform.position;
        float angle = Mathf.Atan2(lookPos.y, lookPos.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(angle, Vector3.forward);
    }

    if (Input.GetKey(upButton)) vertical = 1;
    else if (Input.GetKey(downButton)) vertical = -1; else vertical = 0;

    if (Input.GetKey(leftButton)) horizontal = -1;
    else if (Input.GetKey(rightButton)) horizontal = 1; else horizontal = 0;

    if (projectAxis == ProjectAxis.onlyX)
    {
        direction = new Vector2(horizontal, 0);
    }
    else
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(addForceButton)) speed += addForce; else if (Input.GetKeyUp(addForceButton)) speed -= addForce;
        direction = new Vector2(horizontal, vertical);
    }

    if (horizontal > 0 && !isFacingRight) Flip(); else if (horizontal < 0 && isFacingRight) Flip();
}
}
```

Comment: думаю что ошибка где-то между 98 и 100 строчками кода

Comment: ну это логично) там написано 99 строчка, я новичок, я не знаю много чего

Answer (score 6):

- `Angel` [ˈeɪnʤəl] - ангел
- `Angle` [æŋgl] - угол

Функция для поворота объекта называется [eulerAngles](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-eulerAngles.html) - *угол Эйлера, Эйлеровский угол*

Именно так должна быть написана эта функция в методе Flip()